# Append Dictionary, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, dictionary, append

I am trying to edit my code that I created that is posting text to firebase. I was originally only allowing 8 pictures and descriptions no more, no less. I am now refactoring so the user can pick any number up to 8. I have the checks for the photos working and it uploads the amount picked. I have put checks in place to see if there is a picture or not and if there is it will show the text box to add a description otherwise it is hidden. My problem is I have a dictionary that posts to firebase that is posting 8 descriptions so if i was to create 2 it would fill the other 6 with "" is there a way to check that if an image is nil like I do above then it adds to the dictionary to upload. My function is below..

```
    func postToFirebase() {

    let  post: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
        "photoInfo1": photoInfo1.text as AnyObject,
        "photoInfo2": photoInfo2.text as AnyObject,
        "photoInfo3": photoInfo3.text as AnyObject,
        "photoInfo4": photoInfo4.text as AnyObject,
        "photoInfo5": photoInfo5.text as AnyObject,
        "photoInfo6": photoInfo6.text as AnyObject,
        "photoInfo7": photoInfo7.text as AnyObject,
        "photoInfo8": photoInfo8.text as AnyObject
    ]


    let firebasePost = DataService.ds.REF_BASE.child("posts").child("\(stringPassed)")
    firebasePost.updateChildValues(post)
}
```

The check I'm doing before this to hide the boxes are..

```
if passImage2 == nil {
        photo2.isHidden = true
        photoInfo2.isHidden = true
    }
```

and so on.

I was hoping I could do a check to see if the photo is not nil then if so append the "post" dictionary rather than have them all already coded in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need your photoInfo to be continuos in numbering, you can use

```
let filtered = post.filter { (key, value) -> Bool in
    guard let stringValue = value as? String else { return false }
    return stringValue != ""
}
```

If you need it to be continuos you can filter an array of label texts and then with using of enumarated and reduce, you can create a new dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for this Luzo. This worked perfect for e and I have learnt something new. I now know i can do this .filter to create a new dictionary of items with something in them. Great work